# Putting icon next to button

Tags: javascript, html

i'm running into a problem. Next to the "Show More" there is an icon. When pressed it disappears, because the innerText gets replaced so I tried this:

```
 document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "Show Less <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>" ;
```

This doesn't seem to work any suggestions?

```js
var status = "less";

function toggleText()


{
    
    if (status == "less") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "Show Less";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "Show More";
        status = "less"
    }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="textArea" style="display: none;">
    test
</div>

<button type="button" id="toggleButton" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">Show More <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>

<div id="textArea" style="display: none;"> 

</div
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` if the text string contains html that needs to be rendered:

```
document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to toggle a class instead, here combined with a pseudo for the 2 text variants.

Stack snippet

```js
function toggleText()
{    
    document.getElementById("textArea").classList.toggle('hide');
    document.getElementById("toggleButton").classList.toggle('less');
}
```

```css
button::before {
  content: 'Show more ';
}
button.less::before {
  content: 'Show less ';
}

.textarea.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="textArea" class="textarea hide">
    test
</div>

<button type="button" id="toggleButton" onclick="toggleText();"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>

<div id="textArea2" class="textarea hide">

</div>
```

---

And with the CSS `attr()` you can control the text from your markup, using the `data-*` attribute, here combined with `addEventListener`, which is the recommended way to add event handlers such as the `click` event.

Stack snippet

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#toggleButton');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById("textArea").classList.toggle('hide');
  this.classList.toggle('less');
})
```

```css
button::before {
  margin-right: 5px;             /*  space between text/icon  */
  content: attr(data-more);      /*  get text from attribute  */
}

button.less::before {
  content: attr(data-less);
}

.textarea.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<div id="textArea" class="textarea hide">
  test
</div>

<button type="button" id="toggleButton" data-less="Show less" data-more="Show more"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>

<div id="textArea2" class="textarea hide">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are replacing the whole content of the button here:

```
document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "Show Less";
```

You are overwriting the original text **and the icon** with just `"Show Less"`.

To fix this, you could use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead to set the new text **and** the HTML for the icon:

```
buttonText.innerHTML = `Show Less <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>`;
```

Or you can also wrap the text in a different element to just change that part:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const buttonText = document.getElementById("buttonText");
const more = document.getElementById("more");

let hidden = true;

button.onclick = () => { 
  if (hidden) {
    more.style.display = "block";
    buttonText.innerText = "Show Less";
    buttonText.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("data-icon", "caret-up");
    hidden = false;
  } else {
    more.style.display = "none";
    buttonText.innerText = "Show More";
    buttonText.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("data-icon", "caret-down");
    hidden = true;
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>

  <button id="button">
    <span id="buttonText">Show More</span>
    <i id="buttonIcon" class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>

  <p id="more" style="display: none;">
      MORE
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use unicodes instead? **⮟⮋** This is as easy to use as text!

Leaving here some downwards arrows:

```
⮟BLACK DOWNWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD
```

Hex: 2B9F | Dec: 11167

**Edit**: Full list removed.

Generated from: https://github.com/webdev23/unicode

Comment: While super easy, it is not really an option because most phone browsers and some linux browsers end up seeing boxes

Comment: I understand. It start to be better now. Should I remove this post?

Comment: @Cryptopat It is a valid answer, so don't delete it, but show only **one** arrow syntax and then post a link to the resource.